# Does Möller’s omega-3 fish oil help to improve brain possibility and reduce hight hertbeate?

Tags: nutrition, supplement

Does Möller’s omega-3 fish oil help to improve brain possibility and reduce hight hert rate? 
Is this product from Moller only abuse of well developed brands?

Comment: What is the cause of high heart rate in question: anxiety, arrhythmia or other health condition?

Comment: The root cause is unknown for me. My hormons was in good rates. I have decide to try this nutrition to reduce heartbeate because my average rate in rest state is some hight (some more than 80).

Comment: See a doctor for that, it's not something to try to treat on your own

Comment: Dear friends, thank you  for your answers.

Comment: Dear @Carey please see the main question. It isn't related to my personal physician. The question is only about particular nutrition and how it can help improve people's health.

Comment: @AndreyZinovich Why do you ask about a specific brand then?

Comment: @CareyGregory Beacuse this brand is most developed in our country and has expencive cost. And it is intresitng to know - does it has sence to buy it to improve health.

Comment: Well, in the comments above you made it clear the it's a question about your own personal health, and that's strictly off topic here. The question could be posed in a general fashion that would meet site requirements, but first it would require some prior research on your part. There is a lot of information out there about fish oil and omega-3.

Comment: @CareyGregory Thank you for detailed explanations. Sorry, I took personaly first question in comments, it was my mistake. But I think main question has a some sence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The omega-3 supplement provider](https://www.mollersomega3.nl/mollers_en/fish-oil/omega-3?___store=mollers_en) claims that omega-3 fatty acid supplements are important for proper functioning of the heart and brain, among other.

This review [Reduction of heart rate by omega-3 fatty acids and the potential underlying mechanisms (PubMed, 2012)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3483717/) concludes:

> Recent human and animal studies have shown that omega-3 fatty acids
>   can reduce heart rate.

In [one small 2006 study in men with myocardial infarct](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16616012), omega-3 fatty acids decreased heart rate at rest from 73 +/- 13 to 68 +/- 13 beats/min.

But this alone are just some dry statistical facts. For anyone with a high heart rate of an unknown origin, I strongly suggest to get a diagnosis from a heart specialist before starting any treatment, including omega-3 supplements. The treatment choice largely depends on the cause.